# Calling globally defined JavaScript function from external SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an HTML page with external JavaScript module

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
```

and an external SVG map "img/map.svg".

I need to make clickable objects on the map which will in turn call some global JavaScript function `myJSFunction` defined in "js/js.js". This function will modify the title and contents of the HTML page, hide the SVG map and display a table with some data instead. How can I do this? A naive attempt to set an `onclick` event in the svg code like the following:

```
<g
     id="g170"
     onclick="myJSFunction()">
```

results in error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myJSFunction is not defined
>       at SVGGElement.onclick

Comment: If you're seeing that error then the function is simply not globally defined. Is it in a document.ready handler, for example? It would help to see a working example of the issue, with all relevant code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just defined it as `function myJSFunction() {
    alert("clicked!");
    
}`. And the script loading code is placed after `<object data="img/map.svg" ...`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I run `myJSFunction()` from the console in Chrome, it works!

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, `window.parent.myJSFunction();` works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access parent javascript functions via window.parent i.e. window.parent.myJSFunction()

Comment: I faced a security error with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59279385/590388